# Naming axes in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I understand using `matplotlib`.

```
plt.xlabel('x-axis')

plt.ylabel('y-axis')
```

Can be used in python to name the axes and title so on, just was looking for ward to name the other axes.

[image: image showing desired axis]

Comment: See this example: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: The link is real good and offers all the details I wanted. Thanks @MosteM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
x = [1,2,3]
y = [3,4,6]

p = plt.plot(x,y)
plt.twinx().set_ylabel('right Y lable')
```

[image: output]

Comment: @AKR helpful if you can accept this as a correct answer please.